# XMLHttpRequest - привязка событий к динамически загруженным элементам

Tags: ajax, javascript

```
function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
function Ajax(method, url, id)
{
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
req.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200)
    {
        $(id).innerHTML = req.responseText;
    }
}
req.open(method, url, true);
req.send(null);
}

document.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    $("select_country").onclick = function()
    {
        //Отправляем запрос для получения списка стран
        Ajax("GET", "set.php?country=all", "country");
    }
    //ответ выводит следующее:
    //<span class="country set_1">Украина</span>
    //<span class="country set_2">Россия</span>
    //<span class="country set_3">Беларусь</span>
    //Используя что отправляем очередной запрос для получения списка регионов
    var countryList = document.getElementsByClassName("country");
    for(i = 0; i < countryList.length; i++)
    {
        countryList[i].onclick = function()
        {
            Ajax("GET", "set.php?country=" + parseInt(this.className.replace(/\D+/g, '')), "region");
        }
    }
    //тут еще кусок скрипта который уже подгружает города по выбранному региону
}
```

Работу скрипта обрисовал) Теперь вопрос! Как сделать выполнение скрипта для получения списка регионов а далее списка городов имея динамически погруженный html?

Что-то типа live() в Jquery, но о Jquery речь не идеть!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значит, обработчик надо вешать на document.body.

```
document.body.onclick = function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    e.target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if(/region/.test(e.target.className))
        alert(e.target.innerHTML);
    return false;
}
```