# Как повесить обработчик события на элементы загруженные Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Не могу повесить Событие onchange на элементы созданные динамически после Ajax запроса.

jQuery скрипт на фронтенде  обращается к серверу, он отправляет туда запрос с двумя параметрами: `lines` - количество записей на странице, `pages` - номер страницы. Сервер возвращает ответ в виде JSON массива в котором первый элемент указывает количество страниц: `{ "pages":87 }`,  а все остальные элементы -  это записи которые будут выводится на данной странице.

Количество страниц нужно для создания постраничной навигации на jQuery, зная число страниц, после Ajax ответа  я динамически формирую ul  список  с номерами страниц. Вот как это выглядит ссылка:http://joxi.ru/E2pWpMniKoE9mY Пользователь кликает на номера, после чего к серверу идет новый Ajax запрос.

Пользователь может менять число записей на странице ссылка:http://joxi.ru/gmv6ljVF5joRma

Когда на сервер отправляется новое число записей в параметре line, в ответ  приходит новое значение pages - количества страниц. Но здесь и возникла основная проблема, список выбора количества станиц у меня работает на событие `onchange`, и когда хочу, чтобы он сделал новый запрос на сервер при клике на список ссылка: http://joxi.ru/LmGqn7pFMOPMAl , события не появляется! Не могу понять как можно его запустить?

**Пример возвращаемого JSON:**

```
[ 
  { "pages":87 }, // первый элемент с количеством страниц
   {        
   "feedback_id":"1", 
    "name":"john",
     "feedback":"my 1st comment",
     "feedback_date":"2014-12-16 09:36:29",
      "pages":"0"
  },
  {
 "feedback_id":"2",
  "name":"caty",
  "feedback":"something to write about",
  "feedback_date":"2014-12-16 09:36:29",
  "pages":"0"
  },
]
```

Возможно проблема в том, что я запускаю все через функцию?

**Подключение:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var pageData = {}; // данные для постраничной навигации 
    //console.log($('#records_per_page').text());
    NumberResources(pageData); // выводим список
});
</script>
```

**А вот код самой функции:**

```
function NumberResources(pageData){
//...
$.ajax({
        url: "database-test.php",
        type:"GET",
        data: {"lines": pageData['records_per_page'], "pages": pageData['current_page']},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {

            var pages;  // количество ВСЕХ страниц 
            var output; // строки  выводимые на странице                
            var i = 0;

            $.each(response, function(key, val) { // обходим массив записей

                if(key!=0){

                    // вывод записей    ....

                }else {

                    // получаем число ВСЕХ страниц              
                    pageData['total_pages'] = Number(val.pages); 

                }   

            });

            PageNavigation(pageData); // вызов постраничной навигации   
            $('#update').prepend(output); // выводим в таблицу строки из базы

        //... 

       // ВЫБИРАЕМ ЧИСЛО СТРАНИЦ
       $('select').on('change', function () {                   

            $('select option:selected').each(function() {
                    $('#update').empty();
                    var pageData = {};
                    pageData['current_page'] = parseInt($('li.active .number').text());
                    records_per_page = $(this).val();       

                $('#records_per_page').empty();
                $('#records_per_page').prepend(records_per_page);
                NumberResources(pageData); // рекурсивно обращаюсь к функции с Ajax запросом

            }); 
        }           
    }); 
}
```

Comment: А где код с `click`? можете предоставить?

Comment: такая проблема уже много раз обсуждалась. Вам надо лишь правильно привязать события, тогда они будут срабатывать и для динмически созданых элементов. Вот похожая тема: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/75762/xmlhttprequest-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC

Comment: Код с click в самом низу функции  где коментарий // ВЫБИРАЕМ ЧИСЛО СТРАНИЦ

Comment: Есть пример именно на jQuery привязки события ?

Comment: @inviziblll а всегда думал что `click` и `change` это разные события. хм. чего-то я видимо не знал

Answer (score 2):

Один раз повесьте такое событие

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function (event) {});
```

### UPD

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var pageData = {}; // данные для постраничной навигации 
    //console.log($('#records_per_page').text());
    $(document).on('change', 'select', function (event) {
        // обработка изменений
    });
    NumberResources(pageData); // выводим список
});
</script>
```

Comment: $(document).on('change', 'select', function (event) {var pageData = {}; 
    NumberResources(pageData); // выводим список});

Comment: @inviziblll что вы хотели сказать данным комментарием? Править код вы могли прямо в ответе нажав на ссылку "править" под ответом

Comment: Запускаем эту же функцию, но внутри привязанного события?

Comment: Строку в ответе вам нужно 1 раз написать ВНЕ вашей функции, что бы этот код выполнился только 1 раз

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, все заработало!!!

Comment: @inviziblll пожалуйста, если мой ответ подходит вам то можете слева нажать кнопку "принять"

Answer (score 0):

Вы указали слишком мало данных для ответа: где разметка страницы, где код функции PageNavigation, где ваше события onclick(в коде я вижу change!!). Хотя как мне кажется, вы просто затираете свой SELECT вызовом кода:

```
$('#records_per_page').empty();
$('#records_per_page').prepend(records_per_page);
```

Поэтому оно больше и не срабатывает, так как заново не вешается.

Comment: да там происходит событие change, я сделал опечатку ))) А как очистить элемент, чтобы затем снова его заполнить, но так чтобы были удалены все старые данные? я использовал empty()