# Как повесить обработчик событий на объект, которого еще нет на странице?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице изначально есть одно текстовое поле, на которое я вешаю событие по типу:

```
$("input[name='upsale']").change(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
});
```

Но на странице текстовые поля могут динамически удаляться и добавляться. Пользователь нажимает на плюс, и ниже появляется такое же текстовое поле, на которое нужно повесить этот же обработчик. Как это можно реализовать, чтоб каждый раз не вешать заново обработчики?

Comment: по моему через Promises

Comment: Ну в вашем случае я прочитал пост, просто нужно грамотно все написать чтобы ивентлистенер обновлялся или добавлялся к каждому полю после нажатия на плюс. Надо видеть весь код, (так без кода)ничего не скажу

Comment: _Как повесить обработчик событий на объект, которого еще нет на странице?_ - никак, обработчик можно повесить только на элементы которые уже есть.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как повесить обработчик события на элементы загруженные Ajax](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466009/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ситуациях когда

> на странице текстовые поля могут динамически удаляться и добавляться

, можно обрабатывать событие на таких элементах двумя способами:

- Добавив один общий слушатель события общему контейнеру всех элементов
  *(контейнер не обязательно должен быть непосредственным родителем, это может быть даже `body`. Обработка событий возможна при их захвате или всплытии - примеры ниже работают со всплытием)*
- Добавляя обработчик события каждому новому элементу после его создания
  *(этот способ на самом деле лучше, так как он обеспечивает более предсказуемое поведение. Каждый раз создавать новую функцию не обязательно - можно переиспользовать одну общую)*

---

При использовании jQuery, первый вариант выглядит примерно следующим образом:

```js
$('.foo').on('change', '.bar', function () {
  let rndColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x777 + 0x777).toString(16); 
  $(this).css('background', rndColor); 
}); 

$('.btn-add').click(function () {
  $('.foo').first().append('<input class="bar">'); 
});
```

```css
.bar { display: block; margin: 0.25rem 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="foo">
  <input class="bar">
</div>
<button class="btn-add">Добавить поле ввода</button>
```

А без jQuery, можно реализовать так:

```
for (const foo of document.querySelectorAll('.foo') {
  foo.addEventListener('change', e => {
    if (!e.target.matches('.bar')) return; 
    let rndColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x777 + 0x777).toString(16); 
    e.target.style.background = rndColor; 
  }); 
}
```